# jquery + imgAreaSelect,the imgAreaSelect is not above the img

Tags: jquery, popup

i did the imgAreaSelect on an image that open in a popup,i dindt see the select area but when i close the popup i sew the selected area,what can be the probolme?
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Set `zIndex=100001` in `jquery.imgareaselect.min.js` file. That should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than editing the library, you can set the zIndex as a parameter when creating your selectable region.

```
$('img#pic_area').imgAreaSelect({
    aspectRatio: "4:3",
    [...]
    zIndex: 10000
});
```