# Image cropping area selection not working with popup in jQuery and PHP

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am working with jQuery UI dialog and the imgAreaSelect jQuery plugin. When I combine them, I face a problem with image selection. Other things are working but the only issue is with the image selection. This is a link to the [popup](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form) I am using; this is a cropping [demo](http://www.techumber.com/2012/09/live-image-crop-script-with-php-jquery.html). The image below is the output.
[image].

I'm doing the uploading and cropping process in the dialog. My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/imgareaselect-default.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.imgareaselect.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/process.js"></script>
    <?php
      if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        //error variable init
        $err="";
        $path = "uploads/";
        //allowed image format will be used for filter
        $allowed_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp");
        $imgname = $_FILES['img']['name'];
        $tmpname = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];
        $size = $_FILES['img']['size'];
        if($imgname){
          list($name, $ext) = explode(".", $imgname);
          if(in_array($ext,$allowed_formats) && $size<(1024*1024)) {
            if($ext=="jpg" || $ext=="jpeg") {
              $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmpname);
            } else if($ext=="png") {
              $src = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile);
            } else {
              $src = imagecreatefromgif($uploadedfile);
            }
            list($width,$height)=getimagesize($tmpname);
            if($width > 400){
              $newwidth=399;
              $newheight=($height/$width)*$newwidth;
              $tmp=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
              imagecopyresampled($tmp, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width,$height);
              $image = $path.$imgname;
              imagejpeg($tmp,$path.$imgname,100);
              move_uploaded_file($image,$path.$imgname);
            ?>
              <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                  $("#dialog-form").dialog({modal: true});
                });
              </script>
            <?php
            } else {
              //moving uploaded image to uploads dir
              if(move_uploaded_file($tmpname,$path.$imgname)) {
                //uploaded image
                $image="uploads/".$imgname;
              } else {
                $err="<strong>Oh snap!</strong>failed";
              }
            }
          } else {
            $err="<strong>Oh snap!</strong>Invalid file formats..!";
          }
        } else {
          $err="<strong>Oh snap!</strong>Please select image..!";
        }
      }
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
      .container {
        width: 940px;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
      .logo{
        text-align: center;
      }
      .mini-layout {
        border: 1px solid #DDD;
        -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
        -moz-border-radius: 6px;
        border-radius: 6px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
        box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        padding: 9px;
        width: 900px;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
      .span4,.span5{
        width: 49%;
        float: left;
      }
      .span4{
        border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
      }
      .span5{
        width: 45%;
        padding:0 1em;
      }
      .span7{
        clear: both;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 320px;
        padding: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
      }
      #imgc{
        margin: 0 0.3em;
        border:5px solid #eee;
        max-width: 400px;
      }
      div.frame {
        background: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: solid 2px #ddd;
      }
      input[type="file"],button{
        padding: 5px 20px;
        background: #333;
        color: #fff;
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 4px;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      h1{
        color: #0089ca;
      }
    </style>
    <style>
      body { font-size: 62.5%; }
      label, input { display:block; }
      input.text { margin-bottom:12px; width:95%; padding: .4em; }
      fieldset { padding:0; border:0; margin-top:25px; }
      h1 { font-size: 1.2em; margin: .6em 0; }
      div#users-contain { width: 350px; margin: 20px 0; }
      div#users-contain table { margin: 1em 0; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; }
      div#users-contain table td, div#users-contain table th { border: 1px solid #eee; padding: .6em 10px; text-align: left; }
      .ui-dialog .ui-state-error { padding: .3em; }
      .validateTips { border: 1px solid transparent; padding: 0.3em; }
    </style>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $("#dialog-form").dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          height: 500,
          width: 650,
          modal: true,
          buttons: {
            Cancel: function() {
              $(this).dialog("close");
            }
          },
          close: function() {
            allFields.val("").removeClass("ui-state-error");
          }
        });
        $("#create-user" )
          .button()
          .click(function() {
            $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
          });
        });
      </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="dialog-form">
      <fieldset>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="mini-layout">
            <div class="span4">
              <?php 
              //if image uploaded this section will shown
                if(isset($image)) {
                  echo "<h1>Select an area on image</h1><img style='' src='".@$image."' id=\"imgc\" style='width:100%' >";
                }
              ?>
            </div>
            <div class="span5">
              <?php
              //if image uploaded this section will be shown
                if(@$image) {
                  echo '<div>';
                  echo '<h1>Preview</h1>';
                  echo '<div class="frame"  width: 100%; height: 100px;">';
                  echo '<div id="preview" style="width: 100%; height: 100px; overflow: hidden;">';
                  echo '<img src="'.@$image.'" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">';
                  echo '</div></div></div>';
                  echo "<div id='thumb'></div>";
                  echo "<img src='' id='cropedimg' />";
                  echo '<button id="cropbtn">Crop</button>';
                }
              ?>
            </div>
            <div class="span7">
              <?php
                //if any error while uploading
                if(@$err) {
                  echo '<div class="alert alert-error">'.@$err.'</div>';
                }
              ?>
              <form id="imgcrop" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
                Upload image: <input type="file" name="img" id="img" />
                <input type="hidden" name="imgName" id="imgName" value="<?php echo($imgname) ?>" />
                <button name="submit">Submit</button>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
    <button id="create-user">Create new user</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you link us to your site? I believe it's a matter of CSS positioning but I would need to a place to test with your setup of both plugins

Comment: @koala_dev Sorry for that i am working on local server.but if it is possible i can send you whole project.

Comment: @Mahmood Rehman, I am facing same problem with imgAreaSelect in popup if your problem get solved can you please post answer. Thanks in advanced

Comment: @mahmood and M gaidhane, i had the same problem and i solved it..i can post my code here if you want me so should i?

Comment: try:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572920/jquery-imgareaselect-the-imgareaselect-is-not-above-the-img